# Unable to catch CosmosException when token expired in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

I am using Azure CosmosDB with Blazor WebAssembly (client-side).

I want to catch CosmosException When connection token expires, But not getting cosmos exception for that, (Null exception found)

I have also tried same code in console application, In that I am able to catch cosmos exception that showing token expired.

**Code sample :**

```
        using (CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient(account, token))
        {
            Database db = null;
            db = client.GetDatabase("databaseName");
            Container orgContainer = client.GetContainer("databaseName","containerName");
            
            try
            {
                ItemResponse<CosmosException> response = await orgContainer.ReadItemAsync<CosmosException>("test", new PartitionKey("test"));
                var data = response.Resource;
            }
            catch(CosmosException ex)
            {
                
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
       }
```

[Exception Details of Console Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFvrF.png)

Comment: So you have posted the code that works correctly.

Comment: @HenkHolterman
Yes, this code work correctly, 
Shows cosmos exception in console application but not in blazor web.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the exception occurs outside the try block. Also, make sure you do not instantiate a new cosmos client on each request. This does not perform well. Use singleton and keep alive between requests.

Comment: Exception occurs in try block at [ItemResponse<CosmosException> response = await orgContainer.ReadItemAsync<CosmosException>("test", new PartitionKey("test"));] ................................................

Yes, client connection is created only once,

Comment: So you get a 403 in the response object but no exception?

Comment: 403 showing in browser (inspect -> network), But null exception in catch block.